# In Azure cloud:, not able to query data from a DB2 table when attempting to query sample data using an ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, db2

We are trying to query sample data from DB2 database (available on an On-Premises infrastructure) using ADF (Azure Data Factory) pipelines. We have hosted an ADF SHIR (Self Hosted Integration Runtime) in a VM in the on-premises infrastructure.

We have created a linked service and a dataset for DB2 database. We have also created a test pipeline to test the connection to the database and extract sample data from one of the tables.

Using the test pipeline, we can successfully test the connection to the database however on attempting to query sample data from a table, we are facing the below error and are not able to retrieve sample data:

Error thrown from driver. Sql code: "-805"
The package corresponding to an SQL statement execution request was not found. SQLSTATE=51002 SQLCODE=-805

Comment: Can you share the query you are trying to execute and are you executing it through lookup activity?

Comment: Ask your Db2 DBA to investigate, which package-number or package-name is not found, and the origins, owner of that package. This can happen when configuration is incorrect. Your question is unclear because you give zero facts about your Db2-server, i.e. you should always mention the Db2-server platform (z/os, i series, linux/unix/windows) and also the Db2-server version.

Comment: @ShubhamJain Thanks for responding. We are trying a simple query of select * from [table-name]. We have tried using copy activity as well as lookup activity. For both the result is same. Not able to fetch data from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your Db2 user (or a role or group it has) needs the BINDADD database privilege to bind the package (MSCS001) used by ADF and the Integration Runtime when querying Db2. Once the package is bound you can revoke the BINDADD privilege, because binding a package automatically grants the user BIND, CONTROL, and EXECUTE privileges for that package.

E.g.

1. Grant BINDALL:
   `GRANT BINDADD ON DATABASE TO USER username`
2. Run a query, or preview some data via Db2 dataset in ADF.
3. If successful, you can revoke the privilege:
   `REVOKE BINDADD ON DATABASE FROM USER username`